# Why is my python executable not able to create files but can access data on runtime?

Tags: python, file, pyinstaller, executable

A little bit of context:

- I have made a password manager in python
- I then packed it into a single executable using:
  `pyinstaller --onefile password_manager.py`

Okay first I want to specify that the script works properly when I run it through the password_manager.py file, the executable version also runs properly and when I e.g. create a user and I save the data in a new json file. I'm able to access it on runtime but when I actually close the shell and the program stops running it's like the data has all been lost  and or deleted. I'm looking for a way for the required data to remain on my drive like they do when I run password_manager.py on its own.

P.S.
I can view hidden files in my computer too.

P.S.S.
The link to the code is here: [code](https://github.com/PANKRAV/password-manager)

My [file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kO0e9.png) when I run it through password_manager.py

Here is the executable showing some random [Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOOfO.png) I recently added without closing and restarting the program. These information was supposed to be stored in /data/users.json and /data/password (and is stored there when I just use password_manager.py) but when I actually exit the application they are not present in any way when I rerun the executable(neither the directories that were supposed to be created nor the files).

Simple replication:

```
#mkdir.py
import os
os.mkdir("stack")
```

shell:

```
pyinstaller --onefile mkdir.py
```

I also sadly couldn't find a way to include the executable in this question but you can replicate it with the given command.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: "I also sadly couldn't find a way to include the executable in this question"—that's okay, we'd have to be completely _insane_ to download and run it. We don't need the executable, but we _do_ need to see how you're persisting data. Please [edit] a [mre] directly into your question. We're not going to dig around your code on GitHub.

Comment: I tried making everything more clear. Sorry for the inconvenience I'm kind of new around here.